# VBS change IE integrity level win 7

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-7, vbscript

I am creating a login script
the issue is which IE integrity level.  I need the internet window opened to be a emdium integrity window as in low integrity the script does not run correctly and the page is displayed wrong.
I have found references to CLSID and I have tried the code but it will still not open correctly

```
Set m_objIEBrowser = GetObject("new:{D5E8041D-920F-45e9-B8FB-B1DEB82C6E5E}")
With m_objIEBrowser
 .Visible = True
.Navigate "about:blank"
.AddressBar = False
.ToolBar = False
.StatusBar = False
.Resizable = False
.Width = 509
.Height = 300
.Left = 0
.Top = 0
.Visible = True
.Navigate2 "\\" & m_strLogonServer & "\NETLOGON\Logon\default.htm"
End With
Do While(m_objIEBrowser.Busy)
Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure the protect mode is off in the zone where m_strLogonServer belongs. Otherwise even if you can make m_objIEBrowser running in medium IL, the navigation will cause a new IE instance created in the low IL as the target of the navigation.

Comment: See also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250483(v=vs.85).aspx to understand.

Comment: that was a much easier solution to my problem. Thank you